# Nextauth deployed on AWS Amplify [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I am using NextAuth (Cognito Provider) and it is perfectly working on my local machine but when deployed on AWS Amplify, it keeps giving me `[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]  https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`  and the request `https://mydomain.sample-dev.net/api/auth/session is 404`

I have followed the documentation and added the required environment variable below:

`Executing command: NEXTAUTH_URL=https://mydomain.sample-dev.net`

`Executing command: NEXTAUTH_SECRET=TestingSecretKey`

`Executing command: NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_SECRET=TestingSecretKey`

my `pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts` is

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import Cognito from 'next-auth/providers/cognito';

export default NextAuth({
   providers: [
     Cognito({
       clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_CLIENT_ID!,
       clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET!,
       issuer: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_ISSUER!,
       idToken: true,
       checks: 'nonce',
     }),
  ],
  debug: false,
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET || process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_SECRET,
});
```

any idea on what am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 4):

The [`[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]`](https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error) error suggests the `NEXTAUTH_URL` environment variable is not accessible for use as a result of misconfiguration.

In order to resolve the error, you primarily need to define the required [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#setting-env-vars) on your AWS Amplify dashboard.

Proceed by select the affected application under *App settings*, then click on *Environment variables* and follow the instructions for that purpose.

Then, click on the *Build settings* (equally under App settings) menu so as to edit your *App build specification* script and make the environment variables [accessible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#access-env-vars) as illustrated below.

```bash
build:
  commands:
    - echo "NEXTAUTH_URL=$NEXTAUTH_URL" >> .env
    - npm run build
```